# chkconfig does not support my script

Tags: bash, init, tomcat

I have looked and looked and none of the threads I have found are helping.
We have a tomcat startup script that we modified slightly for our needs.  It works fine on Centos / redhat 6 boxes, but does not work on centos/redhat 5 boxes.

Here is the output of `chkconfig --add tomcat`:

```
$ chkconfig --add tomcat
service tomcat does not support chkconfig
```

Here is the top part of the tomcat script

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Tomcat 8 start/stop/status init.d script
# Initially forked from: https://gist.github.com/valotas/1000094
# @author: Miglen Evlogiev <bash@miglen.com>
#
# Release updates:
# Updated method for gathering pid of the current proccess
# Added usage of CATALINA_BASE
# Added coloring and additional status
# Added check for existence of the tomcat user
# Added termination proccess
#chkconfig: 2345 20 80
#discription Tomcat Starup Script 
#Location of JAVA_HOME (bin files)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace "discription" by "description:" (typo and missing colon).

RHEL 5 needs "chkconfig:" and "description:", RHEL6 only "chkconfig:".